# Loose SATA power in Dell PowerEdge R300

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

I would like to use software RAID in a Dell PowerEdge R300, but it has no molex or SATA power connectors inside, only non-standard plugs: one to take power from the PSU, and one that supplies it to the backplane (I can't use the backplane).

[image: Dell R300 power connections]

Are there adapters to convert the black connector to molex/SATA power?

I already tried using a SFF-8484-to-2-sata fan-out cable so that I can connect SATA drives to the on-board controller using the backplane, but that doesn't work. I don't understand why, because looking at the PCB, the traces go right to the pins in the plug, not to the controller chip on it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? This looks like a completely unsupportable setup, certainly not supported by Dell. What happens when you leave or get hit by a bus, will the next admin be able to figure out this custom-cable mess?

Comment: I'm merely trying to connect the drives to the on-board sata, not the hardware raid controller. All I'm missing is power.

Comment: I don't remember this model precisely, but I believe you have to choose between the RAID controller and the on-board one.  Try disconnecting the RAID card to check if that's the case.  But I second what's been said about bad idea and unsupported configuration, regardless.

Answer (score 1):

From the spec

> Maximum Internal Storage 2TB (2 x 1TB) SAS 2TB (2 x 1TB) SATA

You really can't use the backplane ? as I would assume the powersupply can't supply more than those 2 drives efficiently

Comment: That is with the hardware RAID controller. When I connect them to the on-board SATA, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Halfgaar This server sell with a SAS or SATA controller. If your HDD in the backplane are SAS, please use SAS drive, or call Dell and try to get the SATA backplane